# The way of using Model for _Layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm making several pages and they use a _Layout.cshtml page.

Now.. the _Layout.cshtml page uses two models. For example, one for category and one for member information. (i.e., every page use two data model as default)
Then I need to send two data models for _Layout.cshtml. But I don't know how to do.

My trial is following

In Model class

```
public class CategoryInfo
{
    string Data1 { get; set; }
}

public class LoginInfo
{
    string Data2 { get; set; }
}



public class ModelForLayout
{
    ModelOne CategoryInfo { get; set; }
    ModelTwo LoginInfo { get; set; }
}
```

and in Layout page using

```
@model ModelForLayout

<html>
...
</html>
```

but I don't know where I insert data to `ModelForLayout` and send it to `_Layout.cshtml`.

Comment: In your controllers GET method. But this means that every view that uses that layout must have `@model ModelForLayout` which makes no sense. In your layout, use `@Html.Action()` to call a server method that returns a partial view based on `ModelForLayout`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you for the answer! I will try!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your layout uses 2 models I suggest you inject the ApplicationDbContext in the layout and query the datasets for the models e.g

```
    @inject ApplicationDbContext DbContext
    @{
         var someCategory = DbContext.Category.FirstOrDefault();
         var someMember = DbContext.Member.FirstOrDefault();
     }
```

Where "Category" and "Member" are models and using this approach you avoid having to use 2 models.